# Как callvirt может привести к stack overflow?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Рихтер в *CLR via C#. Программирование на платформе Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 на языке C#. 4-е изд.* на странице 201 приводит очередной пример, рассказывая об инструкциях `call` и `callvirt`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не пойму каким именно образом `callvirt` может вызвать тут рекурсивность? Как `base.ToString()` может внутри себя снова вызвать `base.ToString()`?

Comment: Не "base.ToString() внутри себя вызывает", а при вызове базового виртуального метода используется call, чтобы был вызван именно этот метод, а не его переопределенная версия - иначе круг замкнется и будет рекурсия.

Comment: Написанное там не совсем верно (может быть кривой перевод?), `base.ToString()` не является _вызовом виртуального метода_. Ключевое слово `base` указывает на конкретный метод конкретного класса, так что это обычный вызов, без позднего связывания. Поэтому `call` там используется не вместо `callvirt`, а потому что это изначально должна была быть именно `call`.